# Bash wildcard (*) in command causes in correct output to be captured

Tags: git, bash, glob

Excuse the wording of the title, I'm not sure how to have a catchy title for this 'issue'.

If I run the following command in my terminal (Running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6)

`git branch --list [rR]elease*`

It produces the following expected result

```
* Release-x
  release-1
  release-2
  release-3
```

However, If I put the following in a bash script

```
branches=($(git branch --list [rR]elease*))

for branch in "${branches[@]}"
do
  echo "Found branch $branch"
done
```

It seems to take the `*` and echo the branches found and every file/directory name in my current working directory.

```
Found branch README.md
Found branch acceptance-test
Found branch build
Found branch build.gradle
Found branch flow.sh
Found branch gradle
Found branch gradle.properties
Found branch gradlew
Found branch gradlew.bat
Found branch performance-tests
Found branch postman
Found branch service
Found branch settings.gradle
Found branch sonar-project.properties
Found branch Release-x
Found branch release-1
Found branch release-2
Found branch release-3
```

Why do the outputs differ? Currently, this breaks the logic of the script as it expects branches. I want to avoid having redundant checks (check if this is an actual branch) cluttering the script if possible.

Edit: I've tried quoting the `*` and it produces the same result as above.

[Visual version of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkrUx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(git...)` undergoes pathname expansion before it's stored in your array. `* branchname` marks the current branch in `git`. That `*` in the output of the `git` command expands to all files in your current directory when the array `branches` is constructed.

You can turn pathname expansion off with `set -f`. Also, you have to set `$IFS` to just a `<newline>`, otherwise lines with a whitespace would get split into more items (`*<space>branchname` would become `*` and `branchname`):

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'   
set -f
branches=($(git branch --list '[rR]elease*'))    
set +f   
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Or the better way is to use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t branches < <(git branch --list '[rR]elease*')
```

Or you can use a `while` loop with `read`. This will also trim the leading spaces. If that is not desired, use `IFS= read -r ...`:

```
branches=()
while read -r branch; do
    branches+=("$branch")
done < <(git branch --list '[rR]elease*')
```